# How to respond to a large Form1.cs?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been researching MVC and MVP but I'm not sure if they're what I want.

I currently have a lot of Model objects and my view is the main form (Form1.cs)

The problem is that the main form is becoming very large now. For example, when the user hits the undo menu item, the undoButton_Click event handler is invoked. This is fine. The problem is that the code in this event handler is 10 lines (popping the undoStack, pushing the redoStack, updating form controls, et cetera). This may not sound like much but when there are many controls on your form the lines quickly add up.

I've been thinking about it and I want a simple solution. Ideally when undoButton_Click is invoked the method body would be a single line of code. Ideally there would be a class (perhaps deriving from an interface that defines a single Run method or something of the sort) that I would be able to call to be able to perform this undo.

The problem is that undoButton_Click operates on many form controls and member variables of the class. How would this class have access to these controls? I cannot pass the form as an argument because all the controls are private. I really rather not make all the controls public or provide a ton of public properties to access them. Even if I did that what of the member variables that Form1 has like undoStack or the document object?

It is completely unfeasible to pass all the needed arguments because the paramater list would be huge and if changes would ever need to be made it would be a nightmare.

Not really sure how to approach this problem. What I do know though is that my Form1.cs is way too cluttered with logic and manipulation of objects. I merely want it to respond to events and call the corresponding method/class to handle the event.

Thanks for reading and sorry for the wall of text.

Comment: Can you not just break the form into smaller controls or partial views?

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar problem.  My solution is to create partial classes for my MainForm.  I have one for event handlers, one for mouse handling, one for keyboard handling and so on.

I also refactored out some of the utility methods that get used in a number of places into a separate static class.

I also have another partial class for fields that are used across the project.  Finally I use a static class for some fields and properties to reduce passing paramters to methods.  I am sure some folks will tell me that is bad practice but it works for me.

Finally I use an addin to Visual Studio that calculates the complexity or maintainability of the code and then refactor those methods that are large or complex into smaller ones.

Comment: That what I'm talking about but in short & clear phrase. good for you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand what your code is suppose to do, but you should seperate your code to more small methods which have a short code and do few specific actions each. when you get to that level you'll see which of them can be used for couple of controls and which of them are specific for one control only. Forthermore, you will see what parameters each of them need and then you'll have a clue which of them can be in a seperate class and which can be as a private method of a control, and which will need a dedicated method for a private fields.
Wish you luck and success.

Answer (score 0):

I would add `ControlUndo` class with ctor

`ControlUndo(Form parentform, string controlname, string property)`.

Every `control` on the form declare its undoable property by passing to ctor its parent form, its name and property name.

ControlUndo has a method `Undo()` which from `Controls` collection of parent form finds a `Control` object, using a reflection find a property to undo and reverts the value.

After new `ControlUndo` is added to global collection of undoable objects. When `Undo` on form invoked you need just for each element in collection call `Undo()`.

What about UI.

If you have a lot of controls on the form, it's hardly possible that `user` willl need them all in the same time. So you can devide them among different `TabPages`,based on your app logic,  by puting on form all controls, but limit `UI` content on most important things user needs in that precise moment.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to remove as much logic from your UI layer as possible. When you need to perform business logic, that logic should be located in your business layer. The UI should only know how to visually represent your various data, and issue commands to your business layer. You do not need to use MVC to achieve this.

Conceptually speaking, consider a Person class. That would have a set of properties (name, address, name of dog). Your UI would have a set of text boxes, and a reference to the person instance it represents. When changes are made to a textbox, the change is then applyed to the person instance. When you want to undo, you call undo on the person object, and it would be up to that object to restore to its previous state (and allow for a re-do). After the undo is completed, the UI would put the new values into the textboxes, but it shouldn't care *how* the actual undo or re-do was performed.

This can be achieved manually, or by using built-in data binding mechanisms in .NET. My main point is this; separate your logic from your UI as much as possible, and the Form will do nothing more than show stuff on screen, and issue commands. Whenever SQL statements or calculations starts to appear in your buttons' click handlers, you're on the wrong track.

In the concrete example of Undo, you should look at the memento design pattern ([here](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternMemento.aspx) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern))